# Apply Site Policy using JSOM

Tags: csom, jsom

I’m trying to apply a site policy from a SharePoint hosted add-in using JSOM. SharePoint Online.

I have referenced the SP.Policy.js library and tried to use the static methods in the SP.InformationPolicy.ProjectPolicy namespace.

If I manually apply a site policy using the web interface I can use **doesProjectHavePolicy** and **getProjectCloseDate** to get some information about the applied policy.

I can even close the site using **closeProject**.

However, if I try to get a list of available site policies using **getProjectPolicies** I get an empty list even though I know that I have three available policies. No error or similar, just an empty list. I need this list to be able to apply a site policy, that is my goal.

I have also tried to use **getCurrentlyAppliedProjectPolicyOnWeb** to get the current policy but receive an error when I try to load the object saying:
*a.get_$19_0 is not a function* from sp.runtime and *SP.DataRetrievalWithExpressionString.load*.

Code example:

```
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
appContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
hostWeb = appContext.get_web();

context.load(hostWeb);

context.executeQueryAsync(function () {

    policies = SP.InformationPolicy.ProjectPolicy.getProjectPolicies(context, hostWeb);
    policy = SP.InformationPolicy.ProjectPolicy.getCurrentlyAppliedProjectPolicyOnWeb(context, hostWeb);
    hasPolicy = SP.InformationPolicy.ProjectPolicy.doesProjectHavePolicy(context, hostWeb);
    date = SP.InformationPolicy.ProjectPolicy.getProjectCloseDate(context, hostWeb);
    context.load(policies); // Variant 1. Return an object but no policies.
    context.load(policy); // Variant 2, generate an error.

    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            policyEnumerator = policies.getEnumerator();
```

Anyone out there with a working example of a script that apply a site policy in a SharePoint hosted app?

I can also add that I have done the same thing using PowerShell and it works perfectly.

Comment: Quick update. I opened a ticket with Microsoft about this and after some digging with their engineers they found a possible problem, a bug, in the JSOM library for the site policies. We have made a request to the product team to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the problem and also the solution. I accidently failed to load the library sp.runtime.js in a proper way. Everything else in my app still worked so I didn’t notice this apparent problem until I got some support from Microsoft.